# Updating state of React component through devtools console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-manipulation

I am trying to set the value of the `input` field using the `devtools console` in `Google Chrome`

The catch to this task is that the element's state is likely to be contolled by the `React.js` state. I have made this conclusion after finding the property that says `__reactProps`, among the others:

[image]

The element that I am trying to manipulate is located at [TradingView](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=NASDAQ%3ATSLA&interval=1440). If you open any king of asset and find the **Calendar** button on the bottom on the page:

[image]

A modal window will open with following contents:

[image]

I am trying to programmatically set the **date input field** value to any other valid value, but **the problem is**, that after submitting the form - **the old value is being used!** In fact, this could be further confirmed by hovering the mouse cursor over the element before the form submit. After doing so - the value will be reverted to an old/initial value.

I have made a dozen of attempts to permanently change the value from the `devtools console`, but it keeps reverting back to it's initial value no matter what:

```js
var myObj = document.querySelector("div[data-name='go-to-date-dialog'] input");
myObj.value = "2021-09-01";
myObj.setAttribute('value', "2021-09-01");
myObj.defaultValue = '2021-09-01';
myObj._wrapperState.initialValue = '2021-09-01';

var keys = Object.keys(myObj);
var propsKey = keys.find(key=>{ return key.startsWith("__reactProps$") });
myObj[propsKey].value = '2021-09-01';

myObj.dispatchEvent(new Event('blur'));
```

Does `React.js` require some kind of special treatment? Is there a way to `invoke` the new state into the date component from the console and a vanilla js?

The task that I am trying to achieve is done for educational purposes only and is not meant to "hack" or bring harm to any particular software or platform. I would assume this question is relevant to ANY component made by `React.js` on any website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create an input event and set the value using the event:

```
var input = document.querySelector("div[data-name='go-to-date-dialog'] input");
var nativeInputValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.HTMLInputElement.prototype, "value").set;
nativeInputValueSetter.call(input, '2021-09-01');

var ev2 = new Event('input', { bubbles: true});
input.dispatchEvent(ev2);
```

Comment: This is awesome, can you please expand more on this? how you came out with this solution?