# Manipulate React component state for input field with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I tried to set the value of a React input element on [this website](https://www.dhl.de/de/privatkunden/pakete-versenden/online-frankieren.html?type=ShipmentEditorAddressInput)

(please visit the website and try your code, before you paste an answer that is not a solution.)
(i cannot change the react component source code!)

I tried it by:

```
var target = document.getElementById("address.receiver.name2");
target.value = "test"
```

And I can see the change.

[image: this gif shows how the value gets resettet]

But I guess the intern React component state is not changing the value.
Thats why the value is changing back and is not recognised by the React component?!

I really need a solution to set the value of this input fields via the javascript console.

Even if I try to sent a new event by:

```
var target = document.getElementById("address.receiver.name2");
target.setAttribute("value", "test")

var event = new InputEvent('input', {
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true,
  composed: true, 
});


target.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Nothing changes.

Does React check for the "isTrusted" flag from the event?
And if so, is there even a way to set a valid value with an extern javascript function?
And if yes, how can I change values for those input fields?

Comment: You have to create an input event, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75149853/updating-state-of-react-component-through-devtools-console

Comment: yes i saw that thread, but it does not work on that website. i already tried what wrote there.